# Sencha Touch 2 Listview, TabPanel placement error

Tags: listview, extjs, tabbar, sencha-touch-2.1

My code is this:

```
RNM.Communication = function () {
var listView = new Ext.List({
    itemTpl: '(title)',
    data: [
        { title: 'Item 1' },
        {title:'Item 2'},
    ]
});

var tabBar = new Ext.TabPanel({
        items: [
            {
                title:'Notification'
            },
            {
                title:'Report'
            },

        ]
});


var communicationPanel = new Ext.Panel({

    title: 'Panel',
    id: 'commPanelHandler',
    items: [listView,tabBar]
});
this.getComponent = function () {

    return communicationPanel;
}
}
```

But it seems `tabBar`, does not seem to listview,

I want to go to different pages when I press the buttons Tab, I'd appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

```
 var listView = new Ext.List({
    itemTpl: '(title)',
    flex:1,
    data: [
        { title: 'Item 1' },
        {title:'Item 2'},
    ]
});
```